# Is it possible to compress gas without making it hotter?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, momentum, temperature, gas

First of all, this is just a purely theoretical thought experiment:

> Let us consider another situation. Suppose that the piston moves
> inward, so that the atoms are slowly compressed into a smaller space.
> What happens when an atom hits the moving piston? Evidently it picks
> up speed from the collision. You can try it by bouncing ping-pong ball
> from a forward-moving paddle, for example, and you will find that it
> comes off with more speed than with which it struck - Richard Feynman

I think a table tennis only gets more speed at the moment the paddle moves and the ball is in contact with the paddle.

So, what if I lowered it only at the moment when the ball is not in contact with the paddle? => It wouldn't gain more speed.

So could you (theoretically) also compress a gas without it gaining heat, if you move the piston in the billionth second or so where (purely theoretically) there is no collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an ideal gas at $300\, \text{K}$ at a pressure of 1 atm. The ideal gas law gives a density of about $2\times10^{25}$ particles per cubic meter. Suppose we had a piston with an area of 1 square centimeter. The density per unit length of gas particles in the path of the piston would be $\lambda = 2\times10^{21}\, \text{m}^{-1}$. So you'd expect that you'd be able to move the piston a distance of about $1/\lambda = 5\times10^{-22}\, \text{m}$ before it collides with a gas particle. This is an incredibly tiny distance, about $10^{-6}$ times the size of a proton. The upshot is that it's practically impossible for the situation you're describing to occur. As soon as you move the piston at all, it will collide with a gas particle.

Comment: Thanks! I just thought of one more thing: if the piston is pressed down steadily with a force, mechanical equilibrium will be reached at some point. Could this equilibrium also be interpreted in this way?
The piston always moves when there is no collision from the inside (or only so few that the force transmission in the middle is not as high as the external force) so at some point the path lambda is so small that it is only as large as the respective atoms themselves and then there is always a collision, would that be the case if it was compressed to the point of being a solid object?